# Can I return null in vue computed to watch changes in data?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I would like to use vue's computed to detect changes in multiple data and execute the function automatically. But I just want to use computed as a function, I don't want any new values.
On the other hand, computed is not executed automatically unless it is used. So I decided to return null and use {{}} in the template tag to call that computed. Is this the right way to do it? I don't want to use watch as much as possible.

Also, can I write the process I want to execute after being rendered every time in my "afterRendering" function,which without returning anything, and force it to be called with {{afterRendering}}?

```vue
<template>
...
{{afterRendering()}} <!--this will be executed everytime after rendering.-->
{{MyComputed}} <!--this will be executed when any bindings that depend on changes.-->

</template>
...
export default {
  methods: {
    afterRendering: function () {
      //...
    },
  },
  computed: {
    MyComputed: function () {
      if (!!Achanged || !!Bchenged) {
        //now I can watch if A and B have changed.
        return null
      }
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: Could you further explain what is your goal by doing this? And why you don't consider `watch` an option?

Comment: For example, I have 5 arrays A to E, and if any of them are changed, I would like to check all the corresponding checkboxes. If i use watch, the code itself will be long and all 5 will be monitored individually. However, if I use computed , I thought that the code would be simpler because the data used are automatically watched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@TatsuhikoMizuno instead of your `afterRendering` function just use the in-built `mounted()` function, or if you wanted something to run on *every* re-render you could use the `updated()` lifecycle hook. Docs found [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted), and Vue lifecycle diagram [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram).
And yes you can use your computed property in that way, it just can't have any side-effects like assigning a value to a data property for example.

Comment: I see ,but mounted () seems to work only the first time it renders?
I want to execute it every time

Comment: In that case you could use the `updated()` hook. Lifecycle diagram found here.
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram

Comment: That's certainly what I was looking for .

Comment: @TatsuhikoMizuno good to hear. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @TatsuhikoMizuno if you could accept my answer above that'd be great :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not probably what the OP asked for but I consider this a valid alternative approach for the mentioned problem

```js
export default {
    watch: {
        ...['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'].reduce((obj, currentValue) => {
            obj[currentValue] = {
                handler: () => {
                    // Do something
                },
                immediate: true,
            };

            return obj;
        }, {})
    }
}
```

If you don't want code repetition you could use a **reduce** function over the names of the variables that hold your arrays, by simply using `array` destructuring you can assing this same function to all of your variables. Also this helps for code readability and makes it easier to understand if you actually handle changes in the actual `watch` handler.